# Using map in pair with orElse in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Having to two different collection of objects say  Set say A and List say B.

If set  contains any object need to get the firstobject a string variable say objectA.getName() or else need to get the firstobject in List ObjectB.getPerson().getName() and if both the collection is empty null should be assigned to the string.

Below is my code:

```
Optional<String> name1 =a.stream().findfirst().map(P->p.getName());

String output = null;

if (name1.ispresent()) {
    output = name1.get();    
} else {
    Optional<String> name2 =a.stream().findfirst().map(p1->p1.getPerson().getName());

    if (name2.ispresent()) {
        output = name2.get();
    }
}
```

Here I am getting the correct value. Please help me to attain same using map in pair with orElse.

Comment: If this works, why change it?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
    Set<String> a = ...
    List<String> b = ...

    String output = a.stream()
                     .findFirst()
                     .map(p -> p.getName())
                     .orElseGet(() -> b.stream()
                                       .findFirst()
                                       .map(p1 -> p1.getPerson().getName())
                                       .orElse(null));
```

The important part is the `orElseGet` method on the `Optional`. It is evaluated lazily.

Comment: @dhanyakrishnamoorthy if you think it fits your needs you can mark it as answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.